IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext in GitHub Actions pipeline
I am getting IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@74764622 testClass = errors when GitHub runs my pipeline.
However the tests pass when I am running them with maven in Intellij, the problem in the pipeline job.
This is the CI pipeline:
name: CI workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-deploy:
    name: Continuous integration with Maven
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: 17

      - name: Unit tests
        run: mvn -B test --file pom.xml

      - name: Build the application
        run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml

I am using Junit5 and TestContainers for integration testing.
These are the classes which result in errors in the pipeline:
@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class ClassroomRepositoryTest {
    @Container
    static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0.35");

    @Autowired
    ClassroomRepository classroomRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        Classroom classroom = Classroom.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("math101")
                .subject("mathematics")
                .code("random")
                .build();

        classroomRepository.save(classroom);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnection() {
        assertTrue(mySQLContainer.isCreated());
        assertTrue(mySQLContainer.isRunning());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByCode() {
        Optional<Classroom> classroomOptional = classroomRepository.findClassroomByCode("random");

        assertTrue(classroomOptional.isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByCodeWithInvalidCode() {
        Optional<Classroom> classroomOptional = classroomRepository.findClassroomByCode("wrong-code");

        assertFalse(classroomOptional.isPresent());
    }
}

@Testcontainers
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Container
    private static MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0.35");

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mySQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mySQLContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mySQLContainer::getPassword);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        User user = User.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .firstname("John")
                .lastname("Doe")
                .username("john doe")
                .email("john@email.com")
                .password("1234")
                .dateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(1980, 9, 9))
                .build();

        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnection() {
        assertTrue(mySQLContainer.isCreated());
        assertTrue(mySQLContainer.isRunning());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByEmail() {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail("john@email.com");

        assertTrue(userOptional.isPresent());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByEmailWithInvalidEmail() {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail("wrong@email.com");

        assertFalse(userOptional.isPresent());
    }
}

I don't know why the errors appear only on these repository test classes, the other integration tests runs good with no errors.
This is the stack trace from github:
Error:  Errors: 
Error:    ClassBuddyApplicationTests.contextLoads » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@74764622 testClass = com.demo.ClassBuddy.ClassBuddyApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.demo.ClassBuddy.ClassBuddyApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5b67bb7e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3d246ea3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@63611043, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@17d88132, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@dbebc8df], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Error:    ClassroomRepositoryTest.simpleTest » IllegalState ApplicationContext failure threshold (1) exceeded: skipping repeated attempt to load context for [MergedContextConfiguration@35c9e3b9 testClass = com.demo.ClassBuddy.repository.ClassroomRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [com.demo.ClassBuddy.ClassBuddyApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@11c27ace key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5b67bb7e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3d246ea3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@3ae14048, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@34be3d80, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@a7ab0a43, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@17d88132, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef828610], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Error:    UserRepositoryTest.simpleTest » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext for [MergedContextConfiguration@77aabf26 testClass = com.demo.ClassBuddy.repository.UserRepositoryTest, locations = [], classes = [com.demo.ClassBuddy.ClassBuddyApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [[ImportsContextCustomizer@292be875 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5b67bb7e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3d246ea3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@3ae14048, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@34be3d80, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@a7ab0a43, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@17d88132, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ef828610], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

and this one:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.1.2:test (default-test) on project ClassBuddy: 
Error:  
Error:  Please refer to /home/runner/work/class-buddy/class-buddy/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Error:  Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
Error:  -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


After upgrading java version to 21 and spring boot version to 3.3.3, I was also facing the same issue. I checked the surefire-reports. From the reports, I got to know that there are some incompatible versions of few dependencies present in my pom.xml file.
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.11</version>
  </dependency>

I removed the version tag for the above dependencies, it solved the problem for me.
